# MySQL newbie question: Joining a list of strings to expand a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

bear with me, this is probably super easy but I just started SQL recently.

So I currently have a table that looks something like this:

```
SELECT startDate FROM table1
GROUP BY startDate
```

| startDate |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-03-01 |

But I'm trying to expand this into something like this, hopefully with a list of strings defined in the query itself:

| startDate | rank |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | Rank 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | Rank 2 |
| 2020-02-01 | Rank 1 |
| 2020-02-01 | Rank 2 |
| 2020-03-01 | Rank 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | Rank 2 |

From there I have some calculations in mind that I want to do.
Is there any good way to actually do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join the table with a synthesized table containing the ranks.

```
SELECT t1.startDate, t2.`rank`
FROM table1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'Rank 1' AS `rank`
    UNION
    SELECT 'Rank 2'
) AS t2
```